# In react, does a finite state machine replace the role of a router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, finite-automata, state-machine

I discovered finite state machines as an alternative to managing UI state in a react application. I think they are excellent but I am a little confused about how I should be using them.

Should I be building a state machine for the entire app or do I build little machines within each route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this spectrum discussion](https://spectrum.chat/statecharts?thread=b38df159-4b98-4eb5-977d-d80c07202f74) I learned that you can replace a router with a state chart.

For example, https://state-machine-yzgnuxxwmg.now.sh/

However, the first paragraph of https://statecharts.github.io/how-to-use-statecharts.html recommends using statecharts at the component level when starting out.

> When you first learn about statecharts, you might get the feeling that
>   statecharts can be used to describe the entire behaviour of an
>   application, all the way from which screens show as part of logging
>   in, to the state of each checkbox and text field in every screen, all
>   represented in a statechart. That would be a statechart from hell, and
>   an even bigger maintenance burden. Instead, the focus should be to get
>   a grip on the behaviour at the component level, whatever a component
>   might be. A single screen would be a component, for sure. A single
>   text field that might have some particular internal behaviour (e.g. it
>   changes color based on various flags like required or invalid) might
>   warrant that to be wrapped in a component with a statechart to
>   describe its behaviour.